# [UITouchData timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent

Tags: ios, runtime-error, unrecognized-selector

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, and what is `UITouchData`?

I'm using below method to combine two dates (date and time).

```
- (NSDate *)combineDate:(NSDate *)date withTime:(NSDate *)time {

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

//crash at next line
unsigned unitFlagsDate = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlagsDate fromDate:date];

unsigned unitFlagsTime = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit |  NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlagsTime fromDate:time];

[dateComponents setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
[dateComponents setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
[dateComponents setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];

NSDate *combDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

return combDate;
```

}

N.B. btw, I double checked, I'm passing date and time dates objects.

**Update:**

I'm using a `UIButton` subclass to store selected date into it, like this,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TapButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSDate *referenceDate;
@end
```

and at the time of storing the date, I'm doing like this,

```
TapButton *btnStartDate = [TapButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnStartDate.referenceDate = _datePicker.date;
```

if I mouse hover on it it'll show this,

[image]

but when I print it, it logs this,

<__NSArrayM 0xe574340>(

)

and obvious, now error message changed to this,

```
-[__NSArrayM timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime you made *really* ***silly*** mistakes.. ! =)

*Wrong:*

```
@interface TapButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSDate *referenceDate;
@end
```

*Correct:*

```
@interface TapButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *referenceDate;
@end
```

Non-pointer objects should be assigned, where pointer object should be retain so in this case it should be **strong**. Thanks [@Birju](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256605/birju).

#### .. but still the main question is why its changed to `UITouchData` type and then NSArray type?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your object is really NSDate (and not NSArray)!